# How to edit /etc/host in Docker image from jenkins pipeline

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, dockerfile

I have problem and not sure how to solve this. I have a jenkis pipeline which creates a Azure container instance with some images that are pushed (on same pipeline) to a Azure registry. Now I need a docker container image to be pushed on registry but with a modification on the /etc/hosts file. 
 I tried with:

```
RUN  sed -i '$ a 172.x.x.x  host.domain.com ' /etc/hosts
```

and

```
RUN echo >> 172.x.x.x  host.domain.com /etc/hosts
```

And in pipleine I get error:

```
1msed: can't move '/etc/hostsJCkFPo' to '/etc/hosts': Resource busy
```

I red that I can´t do such thing during build phase manually,  so I search and I looked into,  that using "

> --add-host

" you can achieve this.
Thing is that I don´t know how can I do this in jenkins file. I tried with following inside jenkins file (adding just part of docker build):

```
 def imageNametom = 'repo.azurecr.io/container-tomcat'
 def imageNameTagged = imageNametom + ':' + env.BUILD_NUMBER

 docker.build("${imageNameTagged}" , "--add-host=host.domain.com:172.x.x.x").
```

but I get following error:

```
docker build -t repo.azurecr.io/container-tomcat:6 --add-host=host.domain.com:172.x.x.x
invalid argument "host.domain.com" for "--add-host" flag: bad format for add-host: "host.domain.com"
```

How Can I add this into /etc/hosts file? so containers created from that image they all have this hosts file.?

thank you

Comment: Do you have control of the `Dockerfile` that you are using to create the image? Or do you perhaps only know the IP and hostname that you want to add at build time in the pipeline?

Comment: yes I do have control, but dockerfile is used in jenkins during pipeline build, Is used by jenkins in this case.

Comment: Did you try to write argument in quotes as following:`--add-host='host.domain.com:172.x.x.x'`?

Answer (score 2):

You will not have the IP and Domain name at docker image building phase
You only get this information when a container is created from the docker image

So, my suggestion, would be to use Azure Solution Templates which allows you to invoke scripts after the image is created

Here is one example which does modifies the `/etc/hosts` post the provision of VM 
based on docker image

https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/blob/f605b4b13a6d372d9f40142323e128b5e5e58440/slurm/azuredeploy.sh

You can find more examples of Azure Solution templates here 
https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates

Comment: where does that script modified the /etc/hosts? I see something related with a slurm cluster, will check other templates. IS there a Way to run a "az container create command" with --add-host parameter on it?

Comment: You can use the --dns-label in az container create. Even you have the ability to run a script . `az container create -g MyResourceGroup --name myapp --image myimage:latest --command-line "/bin/sh -c '/path to/myscript.sh'"`

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/container?view=azure-cli-latest#az-container-create

Comment: DNS label is for creating a FQDN for container, Will check for option of running script, but this is a tomcar web server which I believe already starts catalina.out script and can´t start a second one.